# Characterization of Time-homogeneous flows for conditional expectation

Tags: pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, flows

Let $X_t,Y_t$ be $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued processes.  It is well known that for every $t\geq 0$, and every bounded function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, there exists a Borel function $f_t:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
f_t(Y_t)=\mathbb{E}[\phi(X_t)|\sigma(Y_t)].
$$

From this, we can define the flow $F_s^t:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
F_s^t\circ f_t (y) \triangleq f_{t+s}(y).
$$

My question is, when is this flow time-homogeneous.  That is, is there a characterization of the square-integrable processes $X_t,Y_t$, for which there exists $\Delta>0$ satisfying 
$$
F_s^t = F_{s+\Delta}^{t+\Delta}
;\qquad (\forall t>s\geq 0)?
$$

Comment: It seems that we need some assumptions even to ensure that $F_s^t$ is well defined, since $f_t$ is typically not unique.

Comment: I also don't see why $f_{t+s}$ can necessarily be written as a composition of some function with $f_t$, since $f_t$ need not be 1-1.

Comment: If $F_s^t$ is instead defined by precomposition it may be more natural then, and defined almost everywhere.